# Disable img Tag

Tags: javascript

I need to disable img tag using javascript. what is the javascript code?

Example :

```
<img id='hrefId' src="/proteus/images/button_find.gif" alt="" />
```

Please help me

Comment: Please explain what you mean by disable img tag?

Comment: @Curt disabled means grey out

Answer (score 3):

Here's assuming you mean "hide" by disable

```
<style type="text/css">

.disabled 
{
   display:none;
}
</style>


<img id='hrefId' src="/proteus/images/button_find.gif" alt="" />


<script languae="javascript">
var myPicture= document.getElementById('hrefId');
myPicture.className = "disabled";
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery, you can either hide the image : `$("#hrefId").hide()` or add a CSS class that would style it as being disabled : `$("#hrefId").addClass("disabled")`...

Comment: In my project, I have not allowed to use jQuery. Is there any javascript code which can disable the img tag

Comment: First tell us what is "disabling" an image. This notion does not exist, so your meaning is not clear to us.

Comment: Sorry for the unclear. The tag starts from <a href .......><img src="a.gif"></a>.. after that it follows with radio button. when they click the radio button , it should disable the <a>... How can i do this using java script...

Answer (score -1):

```
    document.getElementById('headname'+(t)).disabled=true;
            document.getElementById('headname'+(t)).setAttribute("class","disabledcombo");
            document.getElementById('img'+(t)).src='../images/editfin.gif' ;
            document.getElementById('new'+(t)).src='../images/adds1.png' ;
            document.getElementById('new'+(t)).className = "disabled";
```